# How to fix huge repo size on heroku?

Tags: git, heroku

We have an application deployed on heroku. It's over 5 years old.

While the slug size is around 200mb, the repo size is 5gb on heroku
(based on heroku apps:info)

I understand the heroku repo can get bloated over time, but I'm finding different suggestions while searching for a fix.

1. heroku repo:reset
2. heroku builds:cache:purge

I am wondering what's the best way to resolve this issue.

Comment: The slug size isn't a Git thing; the *repository* size is not really relevant; what matters is what goes into the build product. [The official heroku documentation is here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler) (I can't provide anything more than this).

Comment: Meanwhile, if you want to slim down a *repository*, that's basically a duplicate question. The repository consists of all the commits, and to make the repository smaller, you need new (and probably fewer) commits. That amounts to building a *replacement repository*, after which you abandon the old repository in favor of the new one.

Comment: thanks torek, i guess i'm looking for a specific solution for the heroku repository used solely for deployment to a heroku production environment.

Comment: In theory, you should be able to just make a pseudo-repo of the single commit you wish to deploy, with a new orphan branch each time. Whether and how well that works, I don't know.